# Regex match within html tags

Tags: c#, regex

I've got the following two types of output i need to do a regex match & replace on:

```
<span class=Price>$9.99</span>
<span class=RegularPrice>$9.99</span><span class=SalePrice>$4.99</span>
```

What i'm looking to do is match $9.99 in the first example; and $4.99 in the 2nd.  (basically match the contents of the tag if the class is either Price or SalePrice

I've tried a few examples; but they either match the entire span; or start from SalePrice and go forward

What i've got now is:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<span class=Price|SalePrice>(.*?)<\/span>");
```

but it's off a little bit somewhere.  I think the alternation isn't quite right; can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Using a pipe in a regex context (without being within a group `(...)`) will separate everything from its left to its right. It means you actually want `(?:Price|SalePrice)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky enough, .NET supports variable-length lookbehinds:

```
(?<=<span\s+class=\1?(?:Price|SalePrice)(['"])?>)([^<]*)(?=<\/span>)
```

*I added single/double quotes matching pattern around class names, since as a valid HTML they should have it.*

Answer (score 0):

That will give you spans all the time.

```
"<span class=(Price|SalePrice)>(.*?)<\/span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match Price/SalePrice you should use:

```
<span class=(?:Price|SalePrice)?>(.*?)<\/span>
```